# Dynamic class name with prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to assign ng-model names dynamicly so that the ng-model names will be able to be accessed in the controller by typing '$scope.numbers.no1', '$scope.numbers.no2' and so on. 
So far I am trying this code with no result:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in numbersArray" class="numbersRow">
    <div ng-repeat="num in row" class="number" ng-model="numbers['no' + num]">{{num}}</div>         
</div>
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.numbers = {};
$scope.numbersArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
                       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
                       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
                       [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
                       [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
                       [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]];
```

and to test I am executing:

```
$scope.numbers.no1 = 'A';
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:
What i figured out is that I am mistakenly trying to use an ng-model on a div. 
What I am trying to achieve is to pick a random number  out of the 80 numbers and make it's background black to show that it was picked.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Well, a `div` cant have an ngModel

Comment: Otherwise, you can't use `ng-model` in `div`. It only binds an input, select, textarea (or custom form control).

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to be able to pick a number and display 'A' instead of that number or change it's css

Comment: Might be more helpful if you let us know what the end result should be (are you trying to trigger some action on the number on a click, change the value, etc? Why are you trying to bind the number to ngModel in the first place?), that way we can help you get to the end result in the best way.

Edit: beat me to it by 1 second :P

Comment: Something tells me I should use an id istead of an ng-model...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the final result should be - what should, for example, 45 be replaced by? A single example in this case isn't very informative...

Comment: I want a number to be picked and change it's css. Make the background black for example. What if I use ng-attr-id="'no' + num"  instead?

Comment: Again, what do you mean you want a "number to be picked"? We still don't know what your actual goal or the context is

Comment: I think that the ng-model approach was completely wrong. I am editing the question for you to see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/57Pm9mOPebWTfmObcfX1?p=preview anywhere close?

Comment: @Fissio this is very close to what I am looking for, but does it work for more than 1 number?

Comment: Yah. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/vT6sU9XnYJsov4q7euwK?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="row in numbersArray" class="numbersRow">
    <div ng-repeat="num in row" ng-class="{'clickedNumber': numbers[num]}"
         ng-click="numbers[num] = !numbers[num]" class="number">{{num}}</div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above loops over your `$scope.numbersArray`, and put it in `$scope.numbers` (key is input value). Hope it is what you are looking for:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in numbersArray">
  <div ng-repeat="num in row">
    <input ng-model="numbers['no' + num]" /> {{num}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/60c9sf4o/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a very different thing in my mind and I think that I mislead you a little bit with my ng-model approach..